# Text alignment in dropdown checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

so I am creating a custom dropdown menu with checkboxes that will allow for users to display some constant values in a dropdown menu with checkboxes with the values aligned to the left.

Here is my template:

```html
"<div class=\"multiselect-parent btn-group dropdown-multiselect\">\n" +
    "\t<button  ng-click=\"toggledropdown()\" td-ui-margin=\"0\" class=\"dropdownlist-button\" ng-disabled=\"!edit\" type=\"button\">\n" +
    "\t\t<span ng-if=\"customSelect\">{{customSelect}}</span>\n" +
    "\t\t<span ng-if=\"!customSelect\">{{modelList.length}} {{'MULTISELECT_DROPDOWN.CHECKED' | translate}} &nbsp;<i class=\"caret\"></i></span>\n" +
    "\t</button>\n" +
    "\t<ul class=\"dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form\" ng-style=\"{display: open ? 'block' : 'none', height : '200px' }\" style=\"overflow: scroll\" >\n" +
    "\t\t<li td-ui-margin=\"5\">\n" +
    "\t\t\t<span class=\"headerPointer\" ng-click=\"selectAll()\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></span> {{'MULTISELECT_DROPDOWN.CHECKALL' | translate}} </span>\n" +
    "\t\t</li>\n" +
    "\t\t<li ui-margin=\"5\">\n" +
    "\t\t\t<span class=\"headerPointer\" ng-click=\"deselectAll();\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-remove\"></span> {{'MULTISELECT_DROPDOWN.UNCHECKALL' | translate}} </span>\n" +
    "\t\t</li>\n" +
    "\t\t<li  class=\"divider\"></li>\n" +
    "\t\t<li role=\"presentation\" ng-repeat=\"option in options  | orderBy : 'id'\"  ui-margin=\"5\">\n" +
    "\t\t\t<span class=\"td-checkbox-div-wrapper headerPointer\" ><input type=\"checkbox\"  ng-click=\"selectItem(option)\" ng-checked=\"isChecked(option)\">\n" +
    "\t\t\t<label>{{option[field]}}</label></span>\n" +
    "\t\t</li>\n" +
    "\t</ul>\n" +
    "</div>\n"
```

here is where I am using the template and populating it

```html
 <div class=\"col-xs-2 setup-case-checkbox multiselect-spacing\"\n" +
    "                     ng-if=\"model.frequencyInterval.frequencyIntervalType === 'SEASONAL'\">\n" +
    "                    <multiselect-dropdown options=\"months\" model=\"model.frequencyInterval.customPeriod\"\n" +
    "                                             field=\"period\"\n" +
    "                                             edit=\"true\"\n" +
    "                                             aria-labelledby=\"seasonal\"></multiselect-dropdown>\n" +
    "                </div>\n" +
```

However, when I look at the page that it renders, it does not align properly

[image: Figure 1]

What could I do to align this to the left?

Answer (score 0):

Include this in every line you want aligned left: `style="text-align: left;"`

You could also make a class

```
.left{
    text-align: left;
}
```

and call it like so
`class="left"`

Can you please edit your post to include the CSS as well?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css file

```
.td-checkbox-div-wrapper{
     text-align: left;
    }
```